# How many demon forms does Mirajane have?

Tags: fairy-tail

As what I've known, Mirajane has only [3 forms](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Mirajane_Strauss#Magic_and_Abilities) :

1. Satan Soul
2. Halphas
3. Sitri

I wonder if how many demon forms does Mirajane have (not yet discovered)? Is it three forms only?

Comment: In the meantime, Sayla was taken over too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to  Mashima, says that there are 72 demon forms of Mirajane, but It was not yet revealed in manga and anime,

Mashima has went an interesting way with Mira's powers. 
Though if you know about demons from the Goetia list or other animes you probably already sort of know.

Lisanna has things like Animal Soul: Rabbit, Animal Soul: Tigress 
Elfman has Beast Soul: Weretiger, Beast Soul: Lizardman

Animals and Beasts. 
Though in Mira's case of course she'll have demons for her forms, and Mashima has decided to get them from the Ars Goetia list. 
So it'd look like for her, Satan Soul: Sitri, Satan Soul: Eligos etc.

Here's the list of demons:

- King Baal (bael)
- Duke Agares
- Prince Vassago
- Marquis Samigina
- President Barbas
- Duke Valefor
- Marquis Amon
- Duke Barbatos
- King Paimon
- President Buer
- Duke Gusion
- Prince Sitri-Shown
- King Beleth
- Marquis Leraje
- Duke Eligos
- Duke Zepar
- Count/President Botis
- Duke Bathin
- Duke Sallos
- King Purson
- Count/President Marax
- Count/Prince Ipos
- Duke Aim
- Marquis Naberius
- Count/President Glasya-Labolas
- Duke Buné
- Marquis/Count Ronové
- Duke Berith
- Duke Astaroth
- Marquis Forneus
- President Foras
- King Asmodeus
- Prince/President Gäap
- Count Furfur
- Marquis Marchosias
- Prince Stolas
- Marquis Phenex
- Count Halphas
- President Malphas
- Count Räum
- Duke Focalor
- Duke Vepar
- Marquis Sabnock
- Marquis Shax
- King/Count Viné
- Count Bifrons
- Duke Vual
- President Häagenti

[72 Demons](http://www.fairytailbase.com/threads/mirajane-has-72-takeover-forms.3090/)

link to list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_demons_in_the_Ars_Goetia#Prince_Sitri

Comment: unfortunaly, while this may be a good answer i have to give a downvote as this was more or less copied from a "Fairy Tail Theories" forum. i would gladly remove my downvote if you can quote Hiro Mashima's comment to validate as i can't find a credit source on the forum you linked to

Answer (score 5):

#### Satan Soul

[image: Satan Soul]

#### Demon: Halphas

[image: Halphas]

#### Demon: Sitri

[image: Sitri]

I've read some information about the Mirajane's [Take Over](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Mirajane_Strauss) magic:

> Macro (命令, マクロ Makuro): Unable to fully take over an Etherious, Mirajane took over Sayla's Curse, allowing her absolute control over something, from inanimate objects to even people. She uses this to command Elfman to come to where she and Lisanna are.

For now, she had 3 demon take over. She wasn't able to take over an Etherios where she fought  Layla. This is where Layla's true form reveal.

[image: Layla]

Comment: we got a new one yesterday